# Magento /api/soap/wsdl XML Encoding is empty

Tags: api, soap

Quick issue, when trying to access my magento SOAP api WSDL file "/localhost:8080/ecomm/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl" I get the following error in firefox:

XML Parsing Error: XML declaration not well-formed
Location: http://localhost:8080/ecomm/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl
Line Number 1, Column 31:

It looks like the response doesnt have an encoding version where it was previously UTF-8. I don't know what the cause is.

/app/core/api/etc/wsdl.xml has the correct encoding="UTF-8" encoding parameter in the  opening tag.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the encoding probably you have some module with an error in the xml declaration, try to disable recent installed/updated modules then clean the cache and try again.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Disabled all modules, turned out I had some corrupted cached file, the issue was resolved once I cleared the cache. Thank you!